# Support - Request for a new Tag

Tags: support

Apparently, no matter what I do, I can't post a question without a Tag, and I can't make a Tag since I don't have 300 reputations or whatnot... it's for the game "Harry Potter Hogwarts Mystery"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, just tag your game with something relevant ([pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc), [harry-potter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) etc) and leave a comment on your post asking someone to create a tag. Next time someone with enough reputation sees your post, they'll likely edit in the tag.

You may also post on [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) about it if you have enough reputation.